# Send post data through winform

Tags: c#, jquery, winforms

I have a device hooked up through ethernet on a static IP. There is an html interface to communicate with the device. The interface monitors the io of the device. It has configuration settings to change things such as the IP Address, Subnet Mask, MAC Address, and Default Gateway. It is also how you send commands to the device.

I want to make a C# Windows form to represent only the functionality I need. Where I am getting caught up is in sending the commands from the form.

The html interface is using jquery to send commands back to the device.

`function sendCMD(indata) {$.post("setcmd.cgx", indata, function (data) {});`

`sendCMD({ver : "1",cmd : "abf"});`

I am currently trying to send the post back through a WebRequest, which is just returning the html of URI. I have come to the conclusion that I shouldn't be using WebRequest for this and/or I am sending the post data incorrectly.

What I currently Have:

```
private void btnAimingBeamOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string postData = "\"setcmd.cgx\", {\n\rver : \"1\", \n\rcmd : \"abn\"\n\r}, function (data) {}";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(

        Uri target = new Uri("http://192.168.3.230/index.htm"); 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(target);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        txtABNStatus.Text = (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        txtABNResponse.Text = (responseFromServer);

        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
    }
```

Any help with the proper method of sending the post and how to format the post data would be most appreciated.

Comment: Look into the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class, which simplifies/removes a lot of this boilerplate HTTP code. It will be able to post data for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to post the data to 'setcmd.cgx' not add it to the data you are posting.

```
// You need to post the data as key value pairs:
string postData = "ver=1&cmd=abf";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

// Post the data to the right place.
Uri target = new Uri("http://192.168.3.230/setcmd.cgx"); 
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(target);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
}

using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
   //Do what you need to do with the response.
}
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed. Thank you for catching that I was posting to the wrong location.

Answer (score 0):

You should watch the request in a debugger like Fiddler, and compare between the real site and the request sent by your code. One suspicious thing in the snippet above is that you're sending the data in JSON format, but claiming that it's "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" instead of "application/json".

You may also need to set headers like User-Agent, and/or cookies or authentication headers.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need multithreading webclient will do the job.

```
 string data = "\"setcmd.cgx\", {\n\rver : \"1\", \n\rcmd : \"abn\"\n\r}, function (data) {}";
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    string reply = client.UploadString("http://192.168.3.230/index.htm", data);
    //reply contains the web responce
```

also if you are using winforms(as it seems you are) you should consider sending with the async method which won't block the main thread(UI Thread)

```
string reply = client.UploadStringAsync("http://192.168.3.230/index.htm", data);
```

if you want to use the HttpWebRequest Class let me know, i will edit my answer ;)